# An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused Symfony Docker

Tags: mysql, database, docker, symfony, doctrine

For some reason, when I create function, that creates new Article. I get this error:

```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

But when I run e.g:

```
> php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

Connection seems to be working. Maybe there is some problem with my docker images. Here is the controller with create function

```
  /**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 * @Route("article/create", name="app_article_create")
 */
public function createArticleForm(Request $request) : Response
{
    $article = new Article();

    $createArticleForm = $this->createForm(ArticleType::class, $article);
    $createArticleForm->handleRequest($request);
    if ($createArticleForm->isSubmitted()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($article);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_home_page');
    }
    return $this->render('newArticle.html.twig', ['createArticleForm' => $createArticleForm->createView()]);
}
```

Here is my DATABSE_URL in .env file for symfony:

```
 DATABASE_URL="mysql://appuser:apppassword@127.0.0.1:3306/symfonyBlogDB?serverVersion=mariadb-5.7"
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
services:
 database:
  build:
   context: ./database
  environment:
   - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DATABASE_NAME}
   - MYSQL_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
   - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
   - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD}
  ports:
   - "3306:3306"
 volumes:
   - ./database/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
   -  ./database/data:/var/lib/mysql
```

And my .env file for docker

```
DATABASE_NAME=symfonyBlogDB
DATABASE_USER=appuser
DATABASE_PASSWORD=apppassword
DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
```

Comment: Try this : DATABASE_URL="mysql://appuser:apppassword@database/symfonyBlogDB?serverVersion=mariadb-5.7" where database is the name of your database service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in `docker-compose.yml`. Instead of using address of localhost, I have to change it to `database`, which is name of my database service. Thanks a lot for help.